# Override the Foreign Key Name pointing to Composite Key JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot 1.5.4 with spring-data-jpa and I'm trying to override the auto generated foreign key name during `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`.

For simple id, I was able to override it: `simple_fk`

```
Hibernate: alter table my_entity add constraint simple_fk foreign key (simple_id) references simple
```

But not for foreign key with composite id: `FKms12cl9ma3dk8egqok1dasnfq`

```
Hibernate: alter table my_entity add constraint FKms12cl9ma3dk8egqok1dasnfq foreign key (composite_id1, composite_id2) references composite
```

What is wrong with my code? I also tried `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

Please see the class definitions below.

```
@Entity
public class Simple {
    @Id
    private long id;
}

@Entity
public class Composite {
    @Id
    private CompositeId id;
}

@Embeddable
public class CompositeId {
    @Column
    private long id1;
    @Column
    private long id2;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "simple_fk"),
        name = "simple_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Simple simple;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "composite_fk"), value = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "composite_id1", referencedColumnName = "id1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "composite_id2", referencedColumnName = "id2") 
    })
    private Composite composite;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11180) with the Hibernate which was fix in version 5.2.8

So there are two ways to fix it: Either you update the Hibernate to the version 5.2.8 or up by adding

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
```

to  your pom.xml, which basically will update the Hibernate to the latest version.

or if Hibernate update is not possible or is just too risky you can add legacy/deprecated `@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "composite_fk")` annotation on your
`composite` field which will make you code look like

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "simple_fk"), name = "simple_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Simple simple;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "composite_fk"), value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "composite_id1", referencedColumnName = "id1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "composite_id2", referencedColumnName = "id2") })
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "composite_fk")
    private Composite composite;
}
```